# What is the correct Gnome UI terminology?

Tags: gnome, gui, terminology

There is the top bar, the message thing at the bottom, the activities overview section with all its little bits, but what are they officially called? What is the correct Gnome UI terminology which should be used when talking about certain parts of the Gnome interface, such as in a bug report, or an AskUbuntu question? Can someone tell me all these things? Or direct me to a list of them all?

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The part behind <kbd>Activities</kbd> is called *Activities Overview*
- The panel at the top of the screen is called *Top Bar* or *Top Panel*
- The area at the bottom of the screen (visible only, if you move your mouse at the bottom of the screen in GNOME 3.14) is called *Notification Area*. GNOME 3.16 has an overlay, which will be activated, if you click the small handler at the bottom left corner.

And you are right. It's very hard to find good information about that.

<sub>[Source](https://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/)</sub>